# Django Model not saving to MySQL (Maria DB) while others do

Tags: python, mysql, django, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

My app (Django v 2.2.5) is using MySQL (MariaDB 10.4.6) to store data in its database and has all migrations made and committed. It creates the superuser, when I log in I can creates all related objects, but the `Product` (arguably most important) is not being made. I have tried changing the model, and even removing the `BooleanField` (only unique field different from the models that are storing) and applying the migration but it still does not work. I even deleted the whole database and started anew in hopes of getting around any tricky migrations but that still did nothing for me.
Here is my `models.py`:

```
class Partner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, help_text="Enter the vendor name", verbose_name="Vendor name", unique=True)
    address = models.TextField(help_text="Enter the address of the vendor")
    formula = models.ForeignKey(Formula, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(help_text="enter the vendor phone number")
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text="Enter the vendor email address")
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="vendors")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class ProductType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, help_text="Enter the kind of product this is", verbose_name="Product type")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, help_text="Enter the name of the product", verbose_name="Product name")
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=5,\
         help_text="Enter the price of the product", \
             blank = False, default=0.0)
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(ProductType, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Partner, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="products")


    def __str__(self):
        return self.vendor.name + ": " + self.name
```

Is there any field or metadata argument I am using that is unsupported? I am lost on what I am doing wrong. I tried looking at the logs and cannot see anything obvious to point me in the right direction (I am admittedly not very good at databases).
Here is the error log:

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2019-12-11 21:29:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-12-11 21:29:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-12-11 21:29:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-12-11 21:29:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-12-11 21:29:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-12-11 21:29:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-12-11 21:29:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-12-11 21:29:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=3370115
2019-12-11 21:29:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-12-11 21:29:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-12-11 21:29:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-12-11 21:29:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-12-11 21:29:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-12-11 21:29:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-12-11 21:29:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.6 started; log sequence number 3370124; transaction id 2759
2019-12-11 21:29:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-12-11 21:29:03 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-12-11 21:29:03 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Software versions:

- Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:54:40) [MSC v.1900 64
  bit (AMD64)]
- Django v 2.2.5
- MariaDB 10.4.6
- mysqlclient 1.4.4

I will be extremely grateful for any assistance you can give me.

Comment: What do you mean by "I click save and it does nothing"? No error, no page reload? If so, the problem is not with your DB, but with invalid data in one or more fields

Comment: I mean when I click the save button it loads but never terminates. I tried entering invalid data for control and it showed me an error message but when I fix the errors it just infinitely loads.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue a while back. The issue was with MariaDB 10.4.

Very oddly, it was possible to save data from anywhere in the django application but the admin pages did not work. For example, doing a

Reverting back to MariaDB 5.5 solved the problem.

Comment: Oddly enough the app started saving on its own. I don't recall changing anything. All I did was add pre and post save signal recievers to see where the thing breaks appart and it suddenly started working.. computers are odd.

Answer (score 0):

Are those line breaks in your actual python code? I doubt they are but if so they shouldn't be.

Comment: Actually it works. That's one of the ways to make a multi line statement and even if it didn't it'd stop the server from running by calling an exception in python. It wouldn't affect the database

Comment: I am unsure about that, it throws an invalid syntax error for me if i place them in the same manner in my django models.

Comment: @Pure-Entropy Try [Black](https://github.com/psf/black), it will help you write cleaner code.

Comment: The line breaks are unlikely to be the cause but I'll try removing them. It all worked on sqlite though so I'm wondering why mariadb is being so finicky